# Does GLB file has capability to store lighting information of 3d model?

Tags: 3d, powerpoint, openxml, gltf

I place GLB file in PowerPoint slide. I wanted to know if GLB file has capability to store lighting information of model.

I am referred this documentation but could not conclude if light data can be stored in glb file
https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html

I am a beginner with blender application. Using blender software, I added some point lights and saved the file as GLB. When I reopen those GLB files in blender, lightings are not available.

I viewed various GLB files (available in internet) in Microsoft 3D Viewer. Model lighting appears same for all models. I think Microsoft 3D Viewer uses it's own lighting settings, does not use the lighting information available in GLB.

Once i place the GLB file in powerpoint, model appears dull on comparison with 3D Viewer. So, I think powerpoint also uses it's own lighting settings.

This makes me to assume that GLB do not have capability to store lighting data. This is my assumption. But, I don't find any document mentioning lighting information not supported in GLB

Comment: I think it's more the case that programs may not "understand" all the features of some graphics (SVG) or 3D file formats. Have a look here, where a MS program manager explains how to disable PPT's default lighting, if I understand it correctly: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/3d-model-lighting-inside-powerpoint/d0c0c316-8019-4c25-b0f6-86500e512f91

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with python-pptx or OpenXML. I propose to remove these tags - unless someone can enlighten us.

Answer (score 0):

The glTF file format's support for embedded lighting requires an extension, `KHR_lights_punctual`. When exporting the model from Blender, there's an option in the export setting for whether lights are included. Any viewer that doesn't support this extension can still display the model, but would ignore the lighting, and would need to create its own lighting.

I haven't been able to discover whether Powerpoint supports `KHR_lights_punctual` or not — it would be very helpful if their [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/3d-content-guidelines-for-microsoft-03a7b493-d549-4f1a-9735-f2457adf6261) indicated which glTF extensions they support!

---

It's also possible to 'bake' your lighting before exporting from Blender. This means whatever effect the lighting has on the surface is baked into a single texture per material, and that material is exported with the `KHR_materials_unlit` extension attached, such that no further lighting will affect that material. This extension is more widely supported than `KHR_materials_unlit`, and should look good even if the extension is not supported, so this might be a safer and more portable option for you. You can find tutorials for baking in Blender on YouTube, or use addons like SimpleBake.